# Filtro em Java (Android) com ParseQuery campo tipo Pointer

Tags: java, android, filtro, parse

Como eu faria essa consulta, sendo que este campo (`product`) é do tipo ponteiro, que faz referencia a outra tabela (`group`)?

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> queryProdutos = ParseQuery.getQuery("products");
queryProdutos.whereEqualTo("group", "a431g152aa1" );
queryProdutos.findInBackground((objectGroup, e1) -> {
    for (ParseObject group: objectGroup) {
        Log.i("main", "return === " + group.getString("nome"));
    }
});
```

Em NodeJS consegui resolver fazendo dessa forma:

```
.equalTo("group", { __type: 'Pointer', className: 'groups', objectId: "xxxxx" })
```

Mas no Java (Android) não consigo dessa forma, tentei dessa forma também:

```
queryProdutos.whereEqualTo("evento", new ParseObject("eventos").get(ParamsDao.getEventoId()));
```

Answer (score -1):

resolved.
Resolvido!

```
queryGrrupos = ParseQuery.getQuery("products");
queryGrrupos.whereEqualTo("group", ParseObject.createWithoutData("groups", ParamsDao.getEventoId()));
```